# I get "Please tell me who you are..." error while running gitflow command with ssh-agent defined in Jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, jenkins, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I get the following error while running gitflow command, e.g. `gitflow:release-start` with ssh-agent defined as follows in Jenkinsfile

```
node {
  sshagent (credentials: ['deploy-dev']) {
    sh 'mvn gitflow:release-start'
  }
}
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.amashchenko.maven.plugin:gitflow-maven-plugin:1.18.0:release-start (default-cli) on project testing: 
[ERROR] *** Please tell me who you are.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Run
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
[ERROR]   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] to set your account's default identity.
[ERROR] Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] fatal: empty ident name (for <****@<hashcode>f.(none)>) not allowed
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Unfortunately setting user email and name can not be considered as solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your git configuration on the node is incomplete (probably not existing).

The message thrown gives already the answer. You must configure `user.email` and `user.name` in the git config of the node.

You could either do this by ssh onto your node and run:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

or do this as a `sh` command within the `Jenkinsfile` (before the `mvn` step). You might consider dropping `--global` in this case.

To check the current config, just run.

```
ssh node "git config --get user.name"
ssh node "git config --get user.email"
```

Comment: Adjusted the question. Unfortunately setting user name and email can not be considered in my case.

Comment: Why? You could drop `--global` to set it for the repository only. Obviously your mvn goal tries to push to git, in this case git requires you to provide a name and email.

Comment: Because it runs on Remote Jenkins and I do not have an access. By asking it I wanted to check whether there is another way to solve this problem.